# map function not working in React

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to React JS, I was testing out some functions in fiddler. I am not sure why I get an error pointing to the map function. I am not able to render the array i defined.

Relevant snippet:

```
      {this.props.data.productSpecs.map(function(productSpec){
        <b>Category Name:</b> {productSpec};
      })}
```

Full code:

```
var productCategory = {
    productName: 'SamamgaTV1',
  productCategory: 'Television', 
  productSpecs: ['32inch','black','hd']
};

var ProductComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return( <div>
                        <h2>Product</h2>
              <b>Product Name:</b> {this.props.data.productName}
              <h2>Category</h2>
              <b>Category Name:</b> {this.props.data.productCategory}
              <h2>Specs</h2>
              {this.props.data.productSpecs.map(function(productSpec){
                <b>Category Name:</b> {productSpec};
              })}
           </div>);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ProductComponent data={productCategory} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First you missed to `return`, then you must return **ONE** element.
Here you return a `<p>` and a `TextNode`

Moreover you need to provide a unique key.

Try with this :

```
{this.props.data.productSpecs.map(function(productSpec, i){
        return <span key={i}><b>Category Name:</b> {productSpec}</span>;
})}
```

Comment: Thanks.. this did the job... i dont think i need the key, but it helps when working with bigger applications, it shows how i can pass in IDs ..

Comment: I've just spent almost an hour before I realized I had forgotten the 'return' keyword... #rusty
The key is needed to avoid a warning in the console and avoid a potential mess between items of the list

Answer (score 3):

You need to return value from `map` handler.

```
{this.props.data.productSpecs.map(function(productSpec){
    return (<span><b>Category Name:</b> {productSpec}<span>);
})}
```

If you do not want to (or can't in some situations) wrap content in span, you can create & return fragment (very handy)

```
const createFragment = require('react-addons-create-fragment');

{this.props.data.productSpecs.map(function(productSpec){
    return createFragment({
        bold: <b>Category Name:</b>,
        spec: productSpec,
    });
})}
```

Comment: i tried that also, does not seem to work.. here is my jsfiddle linke https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/59585/

Comment: this fail because you are returning TWO elements. check my answer

Comment: Yes, that's another issue which I overlooked. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you are using a string so you have to use the split method and pass in an empty string such as myValue.split('').map();