# React: I can't print the data fetched

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As I wrote above, I can't print the data recovered from the fetch, I've been on this for some time without any results.

I'm new to React and learning how to use hooks.

The error I'm getting is:
***Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')***

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  useEffect(async () => {
    await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/').then(response => response.json()).then(data => setUsers(data))
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {
        users.map((user) => {
          <div>{user.name}</div>
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Can you kindly help me?

Comment: If you're using `await` there's absolutely no reason to use `then`. That just clutters up the code.

Comment: `users` is undefined before the data is fetched. You need to check for it, or pass an empty array as the initial state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add a default value as empty array to `useState` to make sure that `map()` always exist. (The first render will `map` on an empty array, which is fine since there is not data yet)

   ```
   const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
   ```
2. `useEffect` callback should not be await/async, removed that
3. You didn't `return` anything from your `map()`, I've changed it to:

   ```
   {
     users.map((user) => {
       return <div>{user.name}</div>
     })
   }
   ```

   Or as the short-hand return style:

   ```
   {
     users.map(user => <div>{user.name}</div>)
   }
   ```

   - [map function not working in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999671/map-function-not-working-in-react)
   - [React.js, map is not rendering components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70361452/react-js-map-is-not-rendering-components)

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => setUsers(data))
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {
        users.map((user) => {
          return <div>{user.name}</div>
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
html, body { height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: You should also mention the other necessary change: `return` in the `map()` callback

Comment: Daumn, already forgot that hehe, Added it! THanks

Comment: why do we put an empty array to initialize it? How do I figure this out?

Comment: so in the map you always use the return?

Comment: `map()` only exists on array's, so if you define the state on an empty array, you don't need to worry about calling `map()` if you not yet have received the data. For the second question, yes `map()` needs to return something. You could also use the shorthand like so: `users.map(user => <div>{user.name}</div>)`. Please see documentation on `map()` for more info.

Comment: So that was fine as I did. Only [] was missing in the useState

Comment: Nope, your `map()` callback uses `{}` which indicates a function, in which you need a `return`. If you changed `{}` with `()` in your code, it would have worked fine. I'll add an example.

Comment: Perfect. Now I understand quite well. Last question. Since I've been told that async and await don't do neòla fetch, as I wrote is it ok? or is it a mistake?

Comment: I don;t understand that. As stated in my answer, you should not use async in useEffect like that. This post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332321/react-hook-warnings-for-async-function-in-useeffect-useeffect-function-must-ret

Comment: I was seeing some examples like these:
https://contactmentor.com/fetch-in-reactjs-example/?expand_article=1 So is it advisable to use it with axios eventually?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `users` is `undefined` at the start, you have 2 ways to solve this:

1. set an empty array as default for `users`: `useState([])`

```js
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

2. show something else like a loading text when `users` is undefined

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  useEffect(async () => {
    await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/').then(response => response.json()).then(data => setUsers(data))
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {!users && "loading users..."}
      {
        users && users.map((user) => {
          <div>{user.name}</div>
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```